# How to get more than one char in getopt? eg -abc option -bcd another_option

Tags: c++, getopt

How to get more than one char in `getopt`? 
eg `-abc option -bcd another_option`

My origianl code:

```
while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ild:r:R:")) != -1){

    switch(opt){
        case 'd':   //Do STH
                    break;

        case 'i':   //Do STH
                    break;

        case 'l':   //Do STH
                    break;   
        case 'R':
        case 'r':   //Do STH                            
                    break;
                    default:    return -1;
    }
}
```

However, it is not available for more than one character eg `-abc` or `-bcd`
What should I do for it? Any comment?

Comment: Have a look at getopt_long (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html). Note that long parameters should use `--foo` instead of `-foo`. Also, with default getopt, because `-` implies a single character, `-abc` actually means `-a -b -c`.

Comment: @Gombat, that question is about getopt from bash, this is about getopt from c.

Comment: @g-v: I removed the flag. Nevertheless, it was the same answer.